# Is a GUID unique 100% in the same machine?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

I want to use GUID as my ID System, 
And I want to be sure that I will always get unique ID.

Should I add a test for uniqueness?

Comment: This is entirely up to you, but generating a new GUID (at least if you use the built in functions) is so unlikely to give a duplicate that it's not worth checking.

Comment: It is only statistically unique.

Comment: Old New Thing post [When you start talking about numbers as small as 2⁻¹²², you have to start looking more closely at the things you thought were zero](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160114-00/?p=92851)